# Loop Through ListBox and Determine ListBox Item Order/Position

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, listbox, telerik

I have a ListBox that looks like the attached picture. You can see that Hasbro is the first item in the ListBox, then Matt, then Bif Ban, then Mike's Awesome Stuff. These items are being generated from a SQL table. In that SQL table I have a listBox sort_order column which is just the order that each item appears when they are thrown into listBox. I wrote a Procedure which updates the table that contains the items and sets the listBox sort_order to @sort_order.  When I move items around in the listBox and click the Update Sort Order button I want to loop through the listBox and set the listBox sort_order to whatever the current position the item is in the listBox. For example, Hasbro is currently in listBox sort_order 1, and if I move it to the bottom(after Mike's Awesome Stuff), then it will be in listBox sort_order 4. How could I loop through each item and assign it this new listBox sort_order number value?

I think that it would be something like this but I am unable to get the int id and int sort_order values:

```
foreach (RadListBoxItem item in LBcarDetail.Items)
{
    int id; //how do I access this value? //this is the primary key from my SqlDataSource table
    int sort_order; //and this value? this would be the position in the listBox
 
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["iConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("sp_car_detail_updateSort", conn))
    {
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
        comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@sort_order", sort_order));
 
        conn.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

here is what my RadListBox and SqlDataSource look like:

```
<telerik:RadListBox ID="LBcarDetail" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowTransfer="true" AutoPostBackOnTransfer="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="LBcarDetail_SelectedIndexChanged"
    Height="700px" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="615px" Skin="Outlook" EnableDragAndDrop="true" AllowReorder="true" AppendDataBoundItems="true" AutoPostBack="true">
    <ButtonSettings VerticalAlign="Top" ShowTransferAll="false" ShowTransfer="false" ShowDelete="true"></ButtonSettings>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black; margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;">
            <ul class="details1" style="list-style: none;">
                <li>
                    <label>
                        display_text:
                    </label>
                    <span>
                        <%# Eval("display_text") %></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadListBox>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:iConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [intranet].[dbo].[TableItems] ORDER BY sort_order"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for the sort_order you can use

```
sort_order = LBcarDetail.Items.IndexOf(item);
```